# SQL Update only updates one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, arcgis

This code is only updating one row, why?  It has to do with one of the sub-queries but I am not sure. I'm thinking the WHERE..IN in the UPDATE statement but I am not sure.

```
UPDATE [sde].[sy1].[Valve_evw]
SET [sde].[sy1].[Valve_evw].[MA] 
             = (SELECT [sde].[sy1].[Valve_Join_evw].[MC] 
                FROM [sde].[sy1].[Valve_Join_evw])
WHERE [sde].[sy1].[Valve_evw].[PrimaryKey]  
            IN (SELECT [sde].[sy1].[Valve_Join_evw].[PrimaryKey] 
                FROM [sde].[sy1].[Valve_Join_evw]
                WHERE  [sde].[sy1].[Valve_Join_evw].[MA]
                != [sde].[sy1].[Valve_Join_evw].[MC])
```

Context:

What I am trying to do is update the MA column in Valve_evw using the MC column in Valve_Join_evw.  The PrimaryKey in Valve_evw references equivalent rows as the PrimaryKey in Valve_Join_evw. As in, a single row in Valve_Join_evw will have the same PrimaryKey as a single row in Valve_evw, thus that equivalency can be used to update the records in Valve_evw.  Also the MA column is equivalent in both tables.  [Note: The Valve_Join_evw table is created with ESRI mapping software using the spatial relationship between the Valve_evw and a separate table, this is how the duplicate rows exist]

I am using database views (hence the '_evw') in SQL Server with a default INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger. This combination, views and trigger, prevents the use of table joins to do this update.  I have also tried MERGE but that will not work either.  Therefore I am stuck with the ANSI standard, hence the sub-queries.  This script runs with no errors but it only updates a single row whereas there are about 9000 thousand rows in the tables.

The output message:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: The statement looks for records in `Valve_Join_evw` where `MA <> MC`. For each `PrimaryKey` thus found it updates `Valve_evw`. How many such records exist?

Comment: You update the `MA` field with all `MC` values from Valve_Join_evw. How is this supposed to work? Isn't it a specific `MC` value you want to pick from the table?

Comment: This is no valid Oracle statement. The brackets around names are not allowed (and they cannot be part of the names, because unquoted object names must begin with an alphabetic character in Oracle). You say it runs without errors? Have you been mistaken with the DBMS?

Comment: 1.) The first time I run the statement MA <> MC for all the records.  Subsequent runs will only update a small volume of rows as the data is edited.

Comment: 2.) There are 4 different MC values in Valve_Join_evw that are associated to various records in Valve_evw based on a spatial relationship [as noted] but have to transferred from Valve_Join_evw (MC) to Valve_evw (MA) based on the PrimaryKey.

Comment: 3.) You are right, the test database is SQL Server, my mistake. However the live database is Oracle and will be transferred to SQL in the next few months. Depending on time-frame I may have to change syntax for Oracle, but the actual queries themselves are along ANSI standards (I believe) so they should work for both database systems, with proper syntax of course.

Comment: Interesting to add, if i remove the where clause in the second sub-query to just include all of the primary keys it still only updates one row.

Comment: If it is sql server than tag it as sql server, if it is Oracle then use Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's reduce the eye hurting SQL to what it really is:

```
update sde.sy1.valve_evw
set ma = (select mc from sde.sy1.valve_join_evw)
where primarykey in (select primarykey from sde.sy1.valve_join_evw where ma <> mc)
```

**WHERE clause**

We look for all `primarykey` in `valve_join_evw` where a record's `ma <> mc`. We update all `valve_evw` records with such `primarykey`.

**SET clause**

For a record we want to update, we set `ma` to the value found with:

```
select mc from sde.sy1.valve_join_evw
```

But this query has no where clause, so what value does it select to fill the record's `ma` field? It selects *all* `mc` from `valve_join_evw`, so the DBMS probably picks one of these values arbitrarily. (It would be better, it raised an error.)

**Conclusion**

It is very easy to see which records the statement will update.

Which `primarykey`:

```
select primarykey from sde.sy1.valve_join_evw where ma <> mc
```

Which rows:

```
select * 
from sde.sy1.valve_evw
where primarykey in (select primarykey from sde.sy1.valve_join_evw where ma <> mc)
```

As to the `SET` clause: Add a `WHERE` clause to your subquery that relates the record to select to the record to update (same `ma`? same `primarykey`?) E.g.:

```
set ma = 
(
  select mc 
  from sde.sy1.valve_join_evw vj
  where vj.primarykey = valve_evw.primarykey
    and vj.ma         = valve_evw.ma
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i recomend first to do the select statement and when you are ok with te records retrieved use the same where for the update statement

Comment: Both of the sub-query selects return the data they should, I think.  The first returns all of the MC values and the Second returns all of the PrimaryKey values...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the final script looks like.

```
UPDATE [Valve_evw]
SET [Valve_evw].[MA] =
              (
                SELECT [Valve_Join_evw].[MC] 
                FROM [Valve_Join_evw]
                WHERE[Valve_Join_evw].[PrimaryKey] = [Valve_evw].[PrimaryKey]
               )
WHERE [Valve_evw].[PrimaryKey]  
            IN (
                 SELECT [Valve_Join_evw].[PrimaryKey] 
                 FROM [Valve_Join_evw]
                 WHERE  [Valve_Join_evw].[MA]
                 != [Valve_Join_evw].[MC]
                );
```